# Which ansible.cfg timeout value is "-T" overriding on the ansible-playbook command?

Tags: ansible

The [ansible-playbook documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-playbook.html) says that -T will "override the connection timeout in seconds (default=10)".

In the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file, under the `[persistent_connection]` section, there's **connect_timeout** *(default 30 sec)* and **command_timeout** *(default 10 sec)*.

The ansible-playbook documentation would suggest it's the **connect_timeout** being overridden, but the default value that page specifies doesn't match the **connect_timeout** default value, it matches the **command_timeout** default value.

So, does the -T flag on the ansible-playbook command override the **connect_timeout**, **command_timeout**, or some other timeout not related to either of those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-T` is an equivalent of `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` configuration setting.

```
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
  default: 10
  description: This is the default timeout for connection plugins to use.
  env:
  - {name: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT}
  ini:
  - {key: timeout, section: defaults}
  name: Connection timeout
  type: integer
```

For `ssh` connections plugin is it used as `ConnectTimeout=<value>`, meaning:

```
ConnectTimeout
   Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the SSH server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout.
   This value is used only when the target is down or really unreachable, not when it refuses the connection.
```

`command_timeout` is about:

```
PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT:
  default: 10
  description: This controls the amount of time to wait for response from remote device
    before timing out presistent connection.
  env:
  - {name: ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT}
  ini:
  - {key: command_timeout, section: persistent_connection}
  name: Persistence command timeout
  type: int
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where did you find that link? It could be useful to know for future how to find those mappings for myself.

Comment: CLI switch map is [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.7/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py#L482). As for config helpers, use `ansible-config list`